# I'm stepping down as a moderator of Politics.SE

Tags: discussion, moderators

In recent months, the Stack Exchange has shown that it's not really community run anymore.   My concern started with the capricious de-modding of Ceillo for simply asking questions about a proposed Code of Conduct change before it was enacted.

The recent firing of Robert Cartaino and Shog9 only further show how out of touch Stack Exchange is with the community.  They just don't seem like they care anymore about what meta users think.

Occasionally, they might give an opaque statement, or even say something that gives people hope that things might be resolved, but so far no real progress has been observed.

I've considered resigning for a while now, and I've been thinking of the possibility that moderators might resign as something to leverage in order to get Stack Exchange to right their wrongs. So far there's no sign of progress, so, in order for that leverage to have any teeth, I have to step down.

I've already contacted Stack Exchange to let them know I'd like to step down.  From the sounds of things, it might take them some time to take the diamond away.  I hear that they're short on few Community Managers these days.

Comment: I'm not a power user but I've been on SE for some 5 years' now. I've recently deleted lots of my accounts with a few key ones left over. Just so shocked that SE has been pushing people away so hard recently :-(

Comment: Sorry to see you go. Thanks for all you did.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind words by the way.

Comment: Three weeks after the announcement and the diamond is still there. Even taking the diamond way isn't what it used to be.

Comment: @Alexei Apparently, it would have been Shog9 and Robert Cartaino who might have done it.  I'll submit another request tomorrow if they haven't done it already

Comment: @SamIamsaysReinstateMonica - it was an ironic remark related to how deplorable some aspects of SE have become.

Answer (score 30):

Thank you for your service as a moderator. I've been impressed by your impartial decision making and discretion in using the minimum disruption necessary to keep things civil, informative, and on-topic.

Answer (score 17):

I can’t tell whether to upvote or downvote, so I will instead thank you for what you did while you were here, and be annoyed with the new CEO.

Comment: *Our CEO is the most competent executive to ever rule a company, period, both in person and around the interwebz.* <- that is joke. I hope we can all laugh about it some day.

Comment: Upvote the post. It sends a lasting message to those who come behind us.

Comment: @Machavity Okay. It really hurt, though, since it had a score of +42

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica - the CEO took a free (to the company) resource, stole it from the people who generated that resource, and is aiming to successfully monetize that resourse. As a CEO he seems competent enough if you're one of those right wing types who think greed is good and CEO's only job is to maximize shareholder value :P

Comment: @user4012 you didn't get the parody? I thought this site would remember our great friend Sean Spicer. Well, [here is the original](https://youtu.be/PKzHXelQi_A?t=46) (and [the original parody](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWuc18xISwI)), enjoy. ;)

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica I'm pretty sure user4012 is being humorous too.